# Pipe break itteration?

Tags: oracle, bash, awk, oracle11g

I have a very odd issue, I'm hoping your eyes can help resolve it.

I have a function defined, which connects to an Oracle SQL Database via BASH. Once connected, I use a [HEREDOC](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to pass in a simple select statement that finds a max subscription id and increments it, depending on how many times the function has been called. Here is the code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    PASS=0
    function NewUserSubID(){
    PASS=$(($PASS+1))
    sqlplus "${DB_USER}"/"${DB_PASS}" <<EOF
    set echo on timing on lines 200 pages 100
    select max(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)+${PASS} from ${DB_ENV}.USER_DATA;
    EOF
    }
```

The above code works great when the function is called at the command line:

```
[root@localhost]> NewUserSubID
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2 Production
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2

SQL> SQL> 
MAX(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)+1
-------------------------------------
                                 1082
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2


[root@localhost]> NewUserSubID
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2 Production
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2

SQL> SQL> 
MAX(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)+2
-------------------------------------
                                 1083
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2


[root@localhost]> NewUserSubID
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2 Production
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2

SQL> SQL> 
MAX(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)+3
-------------------------------------
                                 1084
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2


[root@localhost]> NewUserSubID
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2 Production
Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2

SQL> SQL> 
MAX(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)+4
-------------------------------------
                                 1085
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2
```

However, when the function is piped into an AWK statement, the function no longer itterates, which makes no sense! See the output below:

```
[root@localhost] > NewUserSubID | awk 'NR==9{print $1}'
1086
[root@localhost] > NewUserSubID | awk 'NR==9{print $1}'
1086
[root@localhost] > NewUserSubID | awk 'NR==9{print $1}'
1086
[root@localhost] > NewUserSubID | awk 'NR==9{print $1}'
1086
[root@localhost] > NewUserSubID | awk 'NR==9{print $1}'
1086
```

I don't get it. LOL, I really hope I'm just overlooking something simple, but I'm out of ideas.  Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is pipeline used as part of you command here:

```
NewUserSubID | awk 'NR==9{print $1}'
```

Since pipeline creates a subshell therefore changes make in any variable in subshell are not reflected in parent shell.

You can use process substitution to avoid a subshell here:

```
$> NewUserSubID> >(awk 'NR==9{print $1}')
1086

$> NewUserSubID> >(awk 'NR==9{print $1}')
1087

$> NewUserSubID> >(awk 'NR==9{print $1}')
1088
```

Comment: I tried this and while it does allow itteration, it doesn't cut out just the new ID, I still see the whole SQL output, which is what i'm trying to filter out with the AWK.  Is there a better way than AWK?

Comment: Wow! That was perfect.  Can you point me to a wiki or a link where I can read more about this?  I was reading about [process-substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) but I didn't see a part that explains the need for the second ">" and why that makes it all work?  Thanks!

Comment: Read this documentation: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: I get the same issue when I try to assign this command to a variable to be called later .... NEW_USER=$(NewUserSubID> >(awk 'NR==9{print $1}')) ... I gather that I'm falling into the same sub-shell hell issue again ... but I'm not sure how to do it otherwise.

Comment: Hmm that will again create a subshell. Let me try to tweak it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124829/discussion-between-misteralexander-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

When you run the function without piping the result, it runs in the current shell.  When you run a pipeline, however, each command in the pipeline runs in its own subshell.  Among other things, that means that the commands cannot directly influence the shell environment from which the pipeline was launched.  The `PASS` variable is incremented in each subshell, but that change is not reflected in the parent shell, so each subshell sees the same initial value for that variable.

You can either do everything in the same shell, or pass the `PASS` number as a function argument, and manage the increment externally.  For example,

```
#!/bin/bash

PASS=0

NewUserSubID() {
sqlplus "${DB_USER}"/"${DB_PASS}" <<EOF
set echo on timing on lines 200 pages 100
select max(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)+${1} from ${DB_ENV}.USER_DATA;
EOF
}

# Use this instead of calling NewUserSubID directly:
NewUserSubID_Print() {
NewUserSubID $PASS | awk 'NR==9{print $1}'
PASS=$(($PASS+1))
}
```

Beware of trying to capture the output of `NewUserSubID_Print()`, however, for that will cause *it* to run in a subshell.  If you want to capture the output then have `NewUserSubID_Print()` do that itself, and store it in a shell variable for the caller to retrieve.